# Let $z=x+iy$. What is $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \log|z-w|$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \log|z-w|$?

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $z=x+iy$ and $w$ some other complex number. What is $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \log|z-w|$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \log|z-w|$?

I'm having some confusion taking the partial derivatives here with respect to the real component of $z$, $x$ and $y$. I have
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \log|z-w| = \frac{1}{|z-w|}
$$
and
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \log|z-w| = \frac{i}{|z-w|}.
$$
But it seems wrong. Since the function is real-valued, I don't think any partial derivative should be in the complex plane. What am I missing?

Comment: Write $|\cdot|$ as a real number. Take $w$ as a constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z=x+iy$ and $w=\tilde{x}+i\tilde{y}$. Then

$$ \partial_y \log(\vert z-w\vert) = \frac{\partial_y\vert z-w\vert}{\vert z-w\vert} = \frac{\partial_y \sqrt{(x-\tilde{x})^2+(y-\tilde{y})^2}}{\vert z-w\vert}= \frac{y-\tilde{y}}{\vert z-w \vert^2} = \frac{Im(z-w)}{\vert z-w\vert^2}.$$

For the $x$-derivative you get the same with Re instead of Im.